# how to add taglibs and jar files in eclipse for autosuggest?

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I do not know how do i do this?

If I press ctrl + spacebar in eclipse editor , I was able to see jsf tag attributes, .XHTML Attributes and all - now they are gone.

How do I enable them?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So, you're using Facelets? Go to *Window > Preferences > General > Content Types > Text > JSP* and then add `*.xhtml` and set default encoding to `UTF-8`.

With this you'll get assistance for the JSF core `f` and html `h` taglibs, but not for Facelets `ui` yet. You can find another solution [here](http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2008/03/facelets-and-xsd-converted-tlds.html).